# Readable code in python 3 with function calls (lots of parens)

Tags: python, syntax, coding-style

I used to like Python for the readability, but after moving to Pythion 3, that seems to be gone.

Ponder this:

```
print([k for k in hist_full_g(img.scale(12,44))])
```

Maybe it's not as much Python 3 that's the problem, but my coding style, but w/e.

Look at all the parens!

Now obviously I could split it into several local variables, but that would be looong.

```
img_scaled = img.scale(12,44)
histogram = hist_full_g()
histogram_array = [k for k in ]
print(histogram_array)
```

I can also add spaces around parens - actually I sometimes do that, but it's kinda ugly and I've read it's bad practice.

```
print( [ k for k in hist_full_g( img.scale(12, 44) ) ] )
```

How should I write it to be readable and "good quality"?

I'm not talking about this one example, I mean in general. My Python often looks like Lisp, and I don't think it should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make your code more pythonic by replacing the list comprehension with a simple call to `list`:

```
print(list(hist_full_g(img.scale(12,44))))
```

There is never a good reason to do:

```
[x for x in iterable]
```

since `list(iterable)` yields the same result.

You might also want to use two lines to break up the code a little:

```
hist = hist_full_g(img.scale(12, 44))
print(list(hist))
# or
hist = list(hist_full_g(img.scale(12, 44)))
print(hist)
```

You'll notice too that I added a space after `,` in the call to `img.scale`.  Having spaces separate function arguments keeps everything from looking so compact.  In fact, this style is used all throughout [PEP 0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#code-lay-out) (the official style guide for Python code).

---

**Edit:**

Perhaps you would like to use a for-loop:

```
value = img.scale(12, 44)
for f in hist_full_g, list, print:
    value = f(value)
```

The readability may not be great, but it gets rid of all the parenthesis.

Comment: Good, but you still have `)))`. In some editors that auto-complete parens, this is quite pain - they think you want to type the one that's already there and don't let you type another (for something nested inside, perhaps). If there was something like `list ° hist_full_g ° img.scale(12, 44)` it'd be amazing, but I guess there's nothing similar available?

Comment: I think you mean `(list ∘ hist_full_g ∘ img.scale)(12, 44)`. Unicode has a ring operator--no need to use the degree sign--and generally application has higher precedence than composition.

Comment: @chepner Yep, that's exactly what I had in mind. The degree sign is simply because I'm lazy and it is on keyboard :D

Comment: @MightyPork - I had an idea.  See my edit.  Otherwise, I think you are stuck with using multiple lines.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that, but it looks ugly. I'll have to accept this anyway, too bad we don't have composition operator yet